# how to deal with multiple ids in query as i have problem in the following code

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(
      function(){
        alert(this.id);
        $('#comments'+this.id).show();
    }
  );
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
 .comments{
  width:500px;
  height:350px;
  background:#06F;
  display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="1"></input>
  <input type="text" class="title" id="2"></input>
  <input type="text" class="title" id="1"></input>
 <div id="comments1" class="comments">box 1</div>
  <div id="comments2" class="comments">box 2</div>
 <div id="comments1" class="comments">box 3</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple ids...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp here is a that gives the rules for how to use and id.

Answer (score 5):

Element IDs

- Must not consist of a number only
- Must be unique

There is absolutely no way around this.

You need to change your code's structure to reflect that.

If you need to match multiple elements, consider using classes.

Answer (score 1):

The best option when you have multiples that need action is to change the id to a class.  IF you truly have DIFFERENT needs for the id, then you should consider some option that includes modification of the ID in that it CANNOT have duplicates and be valid.

And of course ID must begin with a non-numeric character.

EDIT: some detailed notes regarding naming rules:

- Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
- Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9),
  hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"),
  colons (":"), and periods (".")
- Values are case-sensitive